# How do I count number of item in an array from a String.Join method?

Tags: asp.net, listbox, listboxitem, listitem

```
string lbNames = String.Join(", ", (from ListItem li in lbName.Items where li.Selected select li.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
```

I have this code above that gathers selected item in an ListBox and separated them by names with a comma into one string value. e.g. Bob, Peter, Dick, James

How do I get the number of array I was able to get from the selected value? In this case 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int intArrayNum = lblNames.Length - lbNames.replace(",").Length
```

Comment: Just noticed that the above will be "one less", i.e. 1,2,3,4 will yield 3.  Just add +1 to the above code (unless you want to use it for the array index)